# React+Konva: How to use strokeLinearGradientColorStops?

Tags: konvajs

I am trying to give an ellipse in my Stage (I am using React) a gradient color, like css's border-color with a linear gradient.

I have tried to use strokeLinearGradientColorStops, that will show an empty ellipse. I have also tried using strokeLinearGradientColorStops + strokeLinearGradientStartPoints + StrokeLinearGradientEndPoint, but that turned out weird: when I move my circle around the Stage the gradient will be different, so it was like a gradient color applied to the entire Stage and only showing up on the ellipse

```
<Ellipse
    strokeLinearGradientStartPoint={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
    strokeLinearGradientEndPoint={{ x: 200, y: 150 }}
    strokeLinearGradientColorStops={[0, "blue", 1, "yellow"]}
/>
```

Ofcourse given the parameters of strokeLinearGradientStart and endPoint, I should expect the color to be applied to the stage instead of the element.

If this was the expected result, is there anyway around it? I have also tried to select these elements in css, but Stage maps to a canvas so I don't think I can access the individual elements as they are just pixels.

Comment: Can you make a demo? I just tried this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-ellipse-with-gradient-stroke-dtgut

It works ok.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-konva-ellipse-with-gradient-stroke-bf9ki, so it seems like stuff works fine when there is only 1 circle but when there're two things start acting weirdly

Comment: gotta say though it looks kind of cool when the gradient changes when you move it around even though that is not desired by me:)

Comment: That look like a strange bug in Chrome. I don't see that issue on other browsers. You can try to use a bit different `strokeLinearGradientColorStops` for each ellipse and the issue will go away. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-ellipse-with-gradient-stroke-fw9u7